# Importing rule for python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How should I import modules when I need to a import a package and that package is already imported in the modules that I want to `import`.

Let's say that I have two py files, one is `main.py` and another is `method.py`. In `main.py` I use functions defined in `method.py`. And in both of them I use the functionality of the `datetime` module. How should I import `datetime`? Should I `import` it in both files?

In `main.py`, I have:

```py
from method import *
import datetime
```

And regardless of whether I write `import datetime` in `method.py` or not, or only `import` it in `method.py`, I get an error saying that `datetime` is not defined.

I am confused.
P.S.: I run the `method.py` separately to test it and no error shows up.

This is the error message I get:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\xxx\xxx\xxxx\main.py in <module>
     47 name = ''
     48 # set up a workbook
---> 49 time = datetime.date(year, month, 1).strftime('%B %Y')
     50 writer = pd.ExcelWriter( time + ' xxxx '+ region + '.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
     51 workbook = writer.book

NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
```

I write a `print` statement at the beginning of this function. It was not executed but python is returning error inside the function body.

Comment: import a module whenever u need it, regardless of other locations.

Comment: you import a module in every module you need it. Also, using starred imports is considered a bad practice (outside of a couple, narrowly defined use-cases)

Comment: you should import modules that functions (or classes) use from "method.py"

Comment: I tried importing it in both files but the error still shows up

Comment: please provide the full text of the error message

Comment: If you imported `datetime` at the top of `main.py`, then you should not be getting the `NameError` you're getting — so the only conclusion is that it not the way it really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python `import` statement pulls modules into the current context.  Unlike languages like C and C++, where each `#include`d file sees everything `#include`d before it, each module is entirely independent.

So in your example, `main.py` has no access to anything imported in `method.py` and `method.py` has no access to anything imported in `main.py` regardless of the order things are imported in.

Thus each file should `import` all the modules it needs, and no modules it does not directly need.  If your `main.py` needs `datetime`, it should import it.   If your `method.py` needs `datetime`, it should import it.